Can I return a date from a dataset containing only Year and Hour in Excel?
Dataset looks like this:
2024 1
2024 2
...
2024 8760
2025 1
...

Would like to get to:
2024/01/01 00h00
2024/01/01 01h00
...
2024/12/31 23h00
2025/01/01 00h00
...

Don't even know where to start
Data is 'general'
Should result in 'date' data

The year 2024 has 366 days = 8784 hours, so shouldn't that be 2024/12/30 23h00?

You can use this formula:
=DATE(TEXTBEFORE(A1," "),1,1) + (TEXTAFTER(A1," ")-1)/24
It takes the year from the first part and adds the hours from the second part.
Keep in mind to apply the according number format to the value to display the hours.
As 2024 is a leap year "2024 8760" returns 30.12.2024 not as you put in your data 31.12.2024!

